# Is my general understanding of finding weights correct?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, logistic-regression

I started a course in Deep Learning. I'm trying to make an example in order to explain to myself how the weights are found mathematically.
If what I wrote below is nonsense I'll be glad to hear an explanation. Thanks.

So, for a given image we do **WX+b**. We get some vector **Y** and then we compare it to a desired label vector **L** according to [image]. I'm assuming that we calculate **D** with "**Cosine Similarity**". For simplicity **S(Y)==Y**. So what we're trying to do is to calculate [image] so it will be one.
Let’s say we have image **X** of the letter “a” [image] and two labels (“a”, “b”). Then [image] . We want to calculate **W** and **b** for which we will get such vector [image] that when we’ll insert it into [image] we’ll get zero. We convert **X** to a vector[image]. Since we have 2 labels and size of the **X** is 9, the **W** and **b** are the following: [image].  So, we get: [image]. This gives us the following system of equations: [image]. So, now we need to solve the following [image].

If what I wrote above is not nonsense, I don't quite understand where finding minimum is applied?

Comment: I'll be glad to any comment. I want to know if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

In deep learning finding the minimum means minimizes the cross entropy function. The cross entropy symbolizes the "Loss" of the network. We therefore try by changing the weights and biases of the network to produce an output which minimizes the cross entropy loss. Therefore we minimize D(S,L).

Comment: Finding D(S,L) means to find how similar S and L vectors, right? One way to do this is using "Cosine Similarity", right? So we want to find angle as close to zero as possible, right?

Comment: So, why we use cross-entropy approach to describe the loss function and not "Cosine Similarity", for example, to describe the loss function by minimizing the angle?

Comment: Mostly the theoretic background

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand the relation to my question :)

Comment: Cross entropy has a basis in information theory. It kinda relates to the information needed to reason about the output. It represents the difference of distribution p of the output of the network and the distribution q of the actual problem. Therefore cross entropy has a solid background in theory. Additionally it works well in practice. There are some works that use different functions, e.g. cosine similarity as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4979v1.pdf.